# Real Solutions to the Equation

Tags: trigonometry

Can you please find all real solutions to the equation
$$2 + \sin (\theta )+\frac{(\sin(\theta))^2}{2}+ \cdots = 2$$

Comment: I don't understand what the LHS is.

Comment: I can think of lots of things that might be hiding in that $\cdots$. What do you intend?

Comment: It might help, if you told us what the three dots stand for?

Comment: @Aka I see this is your fourth question here and you've accepted no answers thus far. Please consider going through your questions and accepting your favorite answer to each question which had at least a satisfying answer.

Comment: the three dots mean that the sequence continues on and on

Comment: It looks like it is a geometric series with a factor of $sin(t)/2$

Comment: It could continue on in a variety of ways... the next term might be $\sin^3\theta/3!$ or it might be $\sin^4\theta/4$, among other things.

Comment: @ Git Gud i'm sorry for not accepting an answer. I did not know i was expected to do that. really sorry

Comment: In which case equations boils down to $\sin(\theta)=0$

Comment: Is the next term $\dfrac{\sin^3\theta}{3}$ or $\dfrac{\sin^4\theta}{4}$?

Comment: But the next term could be $\sin^3\theta/3$ or (as suggested by Maesumi) $\sin^3\theta/4$. We are not clairvoyant!

Comment: It could also be $\displaystyle \frac{(\sin (\theta))^3}{3!}$ or even $e^{x^2}$. Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

I take a guess this is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin^n\theta}{n}=0.
$$
For another possible interpretation, see Maesumi's answer.

1)For $|\sin\theta|<1$ we get, using the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)$,
$$
-\ln(1-\sin\theta)=0 \quad\Rightarrow \quad\sin\theta=0.
$$
So the solutions are $\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

2)For $\sin\theta=1$, the series diverges, the equation is not defined.

3)For $\sin\theta=-1$, we get $-\ln 2=0$, no solution.

You solution set is 
$$
\pi\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: If the series diverges due the limit not existing (instead of it being $+\infty$) it doens't make sense to say there are no solutions. Not it makes sense to say there are.

Comment: @GitGud I don't follow you, sorry. For each $\theta$ making the series diverge, $\theta$ is not a solution. No?

Comment: If the series diverges what is the LHS side? The formula $LHS = 0$ doesn't make sense. It's the same as saying $\displaystyle \frac{1}{0}\neq0$. The LHS *is* something which doesn't exist.

Comment: @GitGud Sure, agreed.

Comment: I like you ^ ^${}{}$

Comment: Likewise, my friend.

Answer (score 2):

The geometric series adds to ${2 \over {1-\sin(\theta)/2}}$. If you set the sum equal to $2$ and simplify it results in $\sin(\theta)=0$, i.e $\theta=n\pi$.

A geometric series has the following look $a+ax+ax^2+ax^3+\cdots$. For $|x|<1$ the series adds up to $a \over {1-x}$. Here your $a=2$ and your $x=\sin\theta /2$.

If you provide too few terms of a series doubts grow as to what it might be!

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite G.P

Since the common ratio is  $\frac{(\sin(\theta))}{2}<1$

${2 \over {1-\sin(\theta)/2}}=2$

${{1-\sin(\theta)/2}}=1$

$\sin(\theta)/2=0$

$\sin(\theta)=0$

$\theta=n\pi$.